# Unable to start program "https://localhost:44333" There are no more files

Tags: javascript, debugging, installation, visual-studio-2022, iis-express

1. Background: I had VS 2022 Enterprise version trial working perfectly. After expiration, I downloaded the Professional version which is the version my company has license for. I removed Enterprise version and installed the Professional one.
2. Problem presented without invitation. My application is an MVC app framework 472. Every time I run the application this message is shown: Unable to start program "https://localhost:44333" There are no more files.
3. IIS Express always launches two instances of app in two different ports as shown in image which is surprising for me.
4. After closing the dialog of the message, app runs perfectly but I cannot debug JavaScript files which is something very important for me due to the nature of app.
5. What I have done: Repair VS 2022 installation. b. Uninstall IIS Express and reinstall it. The error persist, always present.

Comment: Is the port been banned?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is an issue reported from windows os, which makes you can't create file when running.

Please make sure there is enough space and check whether another OS have the same problem.

Take a look of this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-